# Same label value for all digit in handwritten digit recognition from photo (not drawing canvas) on android using keras, tensorflow

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, keras, image-recognition

I am working on an Android app that recognizes handwritten Bengali digit from both photo and canvas. I have trained the dataset in python using keras and tensorflow as backend. The app works for digit drawn in canvas and detects all 10 digits perfectly. 
For photo chosen from gallery, I followed the same .pb file and code to detect from photos containing digit (written on white paper with black marker). I took the bitmap value of image by `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),uri)` 
and scaled it to 32*32 (input size). Then got the pixel values and converted color to use in tensorflow. 
When I run the app it detects 5 for all digits with a low confidence. I think trained model is okay since it gives accurate answer when I draw any digit on the canvas. Please help to find why this is happening :( TIA.

```
private void onRecognize() {

    Bitmap scaledImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 32, 32, false);
    image.setImageBitmap(scaledImage);

    int pixels[] = new int[height*width];
    scaledImage.getPixels(pixels,0,height, 0,0,width,height);
    float[] normalizedPixels = normalizePixels(pixels);

    int[] previewPixels = pixelsForPreview(pixels, normalizedPixels);

    Bitmap preview = Bitmap.createBitmap(previewPixels, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    image.setImageBitmap(preview);

    classify(normalizedPixels);
}

private void classify(float[] normalizedPixels) {
    DigitClassification dc = digitClassifier.recognize(normalizedPixels);
    String result = String.format("Digit %s with confidence: %f",dc.getLabel(),dc.getConfidence());
    Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public DigitClassification recognize(float[] pixels){

    tf.feed(input_name, pixels, 1, input_size, input_size, 1);
    tf.run(output_names);
    tf.fetch(output_name,output);

    DigitClassification digit = new DigitClassification();

    for(int i=0;i<output.length;i++){
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Class: %s Confidence: %f", labels.get(i), output[i]));
        if (output[i] > threshold && output[i] > digit.getConfidence()) {
            digit.update(labels.get(i),output[i]);
        }
    }

    return digit;
}
```

Comment: This is a bit hard to diagnose, but I'd recommend printing out the values of the pixels received in the recognize function in both the case that's working (drawn digits) and broken (loaded images). My guess is that there's something different about the processing you're doing in the broken case that's throwing things off.

Comment: Thanks, you're right but i was not doing any processing back then that i needed. Actually on canvas, the digits were drawn with black color on pure white background. So, I have to convert the photo in that way to be recognized. Currently, I'm trying OpenCv to do so though the result depends on ink and background of the handwritten photo. Different threshold gives right output for different photo now. :(